# Is it possible to develope a heirarchical left navigation sites->subsite

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, navigation, migration, public-website

Now we have a scenario here where we are migrating from 2007 to 2010. Our client had been using a custom left navigation but that is no longer functional. I want to build a navigation like the shown below. The site collection is of publishing one.

In the left navigation, I want show subsites under a specific site like:

[image]

"Careers" has subsite "Local Contacts". Local Contacts has subsites "Austria" "Finland"  and so on...

And if we go to Austria -> it has its' own subsites like

[image]

How can I develop such a navigation using a control or an out of the box way in SharePoint 2010.

The referenced navigation can also be seens at the following web:
http://www.storaenso.com/careers/local-contacts/Pages/Localcontacts.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider that :

1. Quick Launch out-of-the-box only supports maximum 2 levels. 1st link
   from Arsalan is actually replacing the navigation with a custom
   control - viable solution.
2. Only Top-Level navigation allows multiple-levels - but you need to
   configure it properly.

Both these menus however rely on the an ASp:MENU control linked to a Navigation Provider (read here for more about these http://kjellsj.blogspot.ch/2012/06/sp2010-navigation-sitemapprovider.html or http://ktskumar.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/sharepoint-navigation-providers-part-1/).

As a simplest alternative (no actual code required - but a change in the Master page), you could actually consider using the ASP:MENU control (just as SharePoint does) and specify it's ID to point to the Global Navigation provider, and change menu Orientation to Vertical, see here http://www.sharepointbinder.com/1/post/2012/03/displaying-the-top-nav-in-place-of-the-quick-launch-in-sharepoint-2010.html

In the default master page there are 2 places where you can find these.

Comment: thank for your reply but I don't wanna show the top navigation as quick launch. I want to display site-- subsites navigation

Comment: The top navigation does actually just that, as the Quick launch, however the difference is in the Context which one chooses to display. So, yes, top-navigation shows Site > Sub-Site hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Geek,

You can use CSS and JavaScript to customize the left navigation or make a Visual Web Part and place on Left Web Part Zone!

Here are some tutorials to start:
[How To Customize Current Navigation (Left Navigation) in SharePoint 2010 To Show Multiple Levels?](http://www.chaitumadala.com/2011/08/how-to-customize-current-navigation.html)
[Expanding and collapsing the left navigation in SharePoint 2010](http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=6b52d069-ff15-4bf8-a157-faf92c9401b4&ID=157&Web=6f35f2df-bca7-45ab-b54e-869b529f079d)

[Top Navigation - Hierarchy based Navigation](http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/customizing-sharepoint-2010-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-%E2%80%93-part-iii/)

Comment: will it work for publishing sites?

Comment: Yes it should work for publishing sites as well